# Download CSV file on client side

Tags: node.js, csv, export-to-csv

i have written a API to export **User collection to  CSV , from MONGODB** . the API is called on a button click and it export the data into CSV ... now the problem is that when this API is called it generates the **RESULT FILE IN MY PROJECT** , i want the result file to get Download on client side , means when user click on EXPORT button it show a **SAVE AS option , USER select the fOLDER , NAME etc and then the file get downloaded on CLIENT COMPUTER** ... any idea how to acheive this ... I,M using **NODE JS , MONGODB** and **JSON2CSV** module for data conversion ... below is my code

```
app.get('/USER/exporttocsv', function (req, res, next) {
    USER.find().select('-__v').lean().exec({}, function (err, products) {
        const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ header: true });
        const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(products);
        fs.writeFile("bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv", csvData, function (error) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log("Write to bezkoder_mongodb_fs.csv successfully!");
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Once your file is written send it to response using `res.download()` https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

Comment: thanks alot mate , it really helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the response.download() method to your code. This will enable the user to download the file on the client-side:

```
res.download('path/to/file-to-download');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add content type to response and set the csv file name just like below.

```
router.get('/csv', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=ireshan.csv');
  res.send("Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarren House,312,3.75\r\nSally Whittaker,2018,McCarren House,312,3.75");
});
```